# Ввод данных в SQLite

Tags: sqlite, android

Переделал, теперь null не передается, все должно работать:

GSQL(активити с базой данных)

```
public class GSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

public static GSQL DBHelper = new GSQL((Context)(new Object()) , "GraphSQL.db", null, 1);
public static SQLiteDatabase SDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

И Record

```
 public void Save() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.HOSTNAME, HostName);
    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.NAMEONMAP, NameOnMap);
    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.MAPNAME, MapName);
    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.TYPEOFCHECK, TypeOfCheck);
    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.STATE, State);
    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.STATUS, Status);
    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.RESPONSETIME, ResponseTime);
    values.put(GSQL.DBHelper.LASTMESSAGE, LastMessage);
    GSQL.SDB.insert("Graph_Table", null, values);
```

Но снова падает в строке с записью в БД -

```
 GSQL.SDB.insert("Graph_Table", null, values);
```

Спасибо за помощь.

UPD1: [image]

Comment: logcat падения покажите.

Comment: Репутация не позволяет вставлять изображения.
http://rghost.ru/53898888

Comment: в 97 строке метод Save класса Record у вас обращается к неинициализованной переменной. Подозреваю, что это sdb, которая у вас равна null. инициализируйте ее.

Comment: 97 строка - sdb.insert("Graph_Table", null, newValues);
sdb я инициализирую:

    public class Record {
 GSQL dbHelper;
 SQLiteDatabase sdb;

Comment: @Xetag смотреть на ваш код это сплошная боль.

Если говорить по существу, то проведите нормальную отладку без `AsyncTask` и только после отладки засовывайте код в `AsyncTask`, а то это напоминает попытку полета на Марс без предварительной подготовки двигателя - геройски, но бессмысленно.

Comment: @Xetag, вы объявили переменную, а не инициализировали. начальное значение sdb у вас null. об этом вам и сообщают - NullPointerException.

Comment: Я потом в том же классе, где осуществляю ввод, инициализирую ее:
sdb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); Но все равно ругается на ту же строчку.

Comment: @Xetag слово отладчик или хотя бы логгер вам знакомо?

Comment: @Xetag, код вы поменяли, это здорово. только теперь наверняка ошибка на другой строке, а именно на той, которую вы добавили, т.е. dbHelper у вас null. @Deadkenny вам правильно написал, передавайте в конструктор Record sdb, вам не нужно два раза создавать и dbHelper и sdb.  
А еще лучше чтобы всем этим хозяйством управлял dbHelper, т.е. в него, в его метод передаете ContentValues, а он уже и базу откроет и запишет в нее что нужно. dbHelper должен инкасулировать общение с базой: и получение данных (возвращать Cursor), и вносить изменения по переданным ContentValues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас **dbHelper** в классе **Record** скорее всего равен null. Передайте его в класс через конструктор например.

**EDIT**

dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() открывает соединение с базой и его нужно закрывать как можно скорее.
В класс Record вам надо передать только SQLHelper и все.

Вот мой примерно как можно сделать.

**SQLDatabaseHelper.java**

```
  public class SQLDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static SQLDatabaseHelper sInstance;

    private final CookiesDAO cookiesDAO;

    private SQLDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        cookiesDAO = new CookiesDAO(this);
    }

    public static SQLDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new SQLDatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Provide Cookies Database Access Object
     * @return
     */
    public static CookiesDAO getCookiesDAO(Context context) {
        return getInstance(context).getCookiesDAO();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        cookiesDAO.create(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        cookiesDAO.upgrade(db,oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    /**
     * Provide Cookies Database Access Object
     *
     * @return
     */
    public CookiesDAO getCookiesDAO() {
        return cookiesDAO;
    }

}
```

**CookiesDAO.java**

```
public class CookiesDAO extends SQLTable {

    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_URI = "uri";
    private static final String COLUMN_HEADER = "header";

    CookiesDAO(SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper) {
        super(dbHelper, "cookies");
    }

    /**
     * Store bunch of cookies
     *
     * @param list
     */
    public void store(List<Cookie> list) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (Cookie cookie : list) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(COLUMN_URI, cookie.uri.toString());
                values.put(COLUMN_HEADER, cookie.header);

                db.insertOrThrow(tableName, null, values);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * Read all of cookies from database
     *
     * @return
     */
    public List<Cookie> read() {
        List<Cookie> list = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, new String[] {COLUMN_URI, COLUMN_HEADER}, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    list.add(cookieFromCursor(cursor));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
        Timber.d("Read %d cookies", list.size());
        return list;
    }

    private Cookie cookieFromCursor(final Cursor cursor) {
        return new Cookie(URI.create(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1));
    }

    @Override
    void create(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sqlCreateTableScript = new DatabaseUtils.SQLCreateTableScriptBuilder(tableName)
                .addPrimaryKey(COLUMN_ID)
                .addColumn(COLUMN_URI)
                .addColumn(COLUMN_HEADER)
                .toString();
        db.execSQL(sqlCreateTableScript);
    }

    @Override
    void upgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        drop(db);
        create(db);
    }
}
```

**SQLTable.java**

```
abstract class SQLTable {
    final String tableName;
    final SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;

    SQLTable(final SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper, final String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Create new table
     */
    abstract void create(SQLiteDatabase db);

    /**
     * Update table
     *
     * @param oldVersion old database version
     * @param newVersion new database version
     */
    abstract void upgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion);

    /**
     * Delete all records
     */
    public void clear() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.delete(tableName, null, null);
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Drop table
     */
    void drop(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
    }
}
```

Используя мой пример можно любую таблицу описать в отдельном классе и потом использовать только объект этого класса. При этом каждое соединение с базой будет завершено как можно быстрее, что не приведет к конфликтам.

**EDIT2**

Замечание по вашим исходникам

> GSQL http://ideone.com/AtFvr6 Record
> http://ideone.com/wf0Rg0

1. Нельзя передавать GSQL  в качестве **Context** объект **(Context)(new Object())**. Хорошим решение будет инициализировать синглтон в переопределенном классе Application.
2. Очень не желательно открывать соединение с базой и держать открытым. Желательно открывать и закрывать его для каждой транзакции. >**SQLiteDatabase SDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();**
3. Измените конструктор класса Record на

   ```
       public final GSQL dbHelper;
   public final SQLiteDatabase sdb;
   public Record (GSQL dbHelper, SQLiteDatabase sdb, String hostName, String nameOnMap, String mapName,
           String typeOfCheck, String state, String status,
           String responseTime, String lastMessage) {
       this.HostName = hostName;
       this.NameOnMap = nameOnMap;
       this.MapName = mapName;
       this.TypeOfCheck = typeOfCheck;
       this.State = state;
       this.Status = status;
       this.ResponseTime = responseTime;
       this.LastMessage = lastMessage;
       this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
       this.sdb = sbd;
   }
   ```

Comment: Я все равно не могу понять, почему в строке сохранения данных программа крашится.

Comment: Для этого выложи исходники SQLHelper и Record

Comment: http://ideone.com/ сюда например

Comment: GSQL 
http://ideone.com/AtFvr6

Record
http://ideone.com/wf0Rg0

Comment: @Xetag, так писать как у вас писать нельзя. начните заново, взяв за основу либо мой код, либо  код @Deadkenny, еще лучше посмотрите гугло-примеры, в частности Note Pad и Searchable Dictionary.

Comment: @Xetag смотрите мое добавление в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо все-таки реализовать класс Record, то его можно потом вычленить, когда разберетесь.

```
public class GSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  ... // тут константы
  private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  public GSQL(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  ... // тут onCreate и onUpgrade

  public Cursor getGraph(){
    return sdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
      new String[] {HOSTNAME, NAMEONMAP, MAPNAME, TYPEOFCHECK, 
        STATE, STATUS, RESPONSETIME, LASTMESSAGE},
        null, null, null, null, null) ;
  }
  public long save(String hostName, String nameOnMap, String mapName,
    String typeOfCheck, String state, String status,
    String responseTime, String lastMessage) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(HOSTNAME, hostName);
    cv.put(NAMEONMAP, nameOnMap);
    cv.put(MAPNAME, mapName);
    cv.put(TYPEOFCHECK, typeOfCheck);
    cv.put(STATE, state);
    cv.put(STATUS, status);
    cv.put(RESPONSETIME, responseTime);
    cv.put(LASTMESSAGE, lastMessage);
    sdb = getWritableDatabase();
    long id = sdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    sdb.close();
    return id;
  }
}
```

В автивити:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getGraph();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ...
    // вообще курсор вернет не одну запись ведь, 
    // лучше передать его в SimpleCursorAdapter и заполнить им ListView
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long>(){
  @Override
  protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // ну тут данные подставляем, которые надо вставить в базу    
    return dbHelper.save(hostName, 
      nameOnMap, mapName, typeOfCheck, 
      state, status, responseTime, lastMessage);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    // получили id если он нужен, вывели, например, сообщение
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Много всего написано уже и непонятно помогло ли что-то окнчательно
У меня падало примерно в аналогичной ситуации - причем на эмуляторе падало, а на реальном устройстве нет :)
Дело было в том, что я в  ContentValues помещал не все параметры, а только чать. ну т.е. некоторые поля записи желал оставить пустыми - по умолчанию равны null
Вот это эмулятор пережить почему-то ну никак не мог.
Переделал на непараметризованный insert, с однозначным указанием имен полей записи которые вставляю и их значений, и всё стало ровно и гладко :)